# CRUD form in MVC and post data to Web Service soap (VB)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, web-services, model-view-controller

I have a data processing application using ASP.NET MVC. The application has form features for create, read, update, and delete (CRUD). I also created a Web Service with VB to do CRUD queries on the database. My question is, how do I POST the value that I input in the ASP.NET MVC application form to the SOAP Web Service (http://mylink.net/service.asmx?op=create)? Can I use AJAX on the Views form? Or is there another way? thanks.

Comment: You don't. You use the WCF proxy generated from the service's WSDL instead, to make calls. ASMX services were deprecated in 2005 and replaced by WCF. Don't use them

Comment: Generating a proxy is easy, and well documented. Right click on your project and select `Add Service Reference`. Add the service's URL to the proper field, and VS will generate a new proxy

Comment: Check the [WCF Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial) tutorials. They show how to create a new Web Service, how to create a client and how to call the service. Don't just assume you can use ASMX - the WS-* interoperability standards didn't even exist when ASMX was created. Clients that expect those standards won't be able to call your web service